# NullPointerException when processing asyncServlet

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, servlet-3.0

I am following [this](http://www.softwareengineeringsolutions.com/blogs/2010/08/13/asynchronous-servlets-in-servlet-spec-3-0/) tutorial -

When I send request like this-

```
http://localhost:9090/AsyncServlet?id=99&dispatch=true&timeout=false
```

I am getting following-

```
Apr 09, 2013 4:01:09 PM com.mycompany.mavenproject1.AsyncServlet doGet
INFO: AsyncServlet: Processing request: 99. on thread: 27:qtp2072997125-27[4/9/13 4:01 PM]
2013-04-09 16:01:09.503:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:/AsyncServlet
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mycompany.mavenproject1.AsyncServlet.doGet(AsyncServlet.java:50)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1004)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I just don't know even where to start debugging. My web.xml looks like this-

```xml
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0"> 

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AsyncServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.mycompany.mavenproject1.AsyncServlet
    </servlet-class>        
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>

</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AsyncServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/AsyncServlet/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Line50: executor.execute(new AsyncRequestProcessor(asyncCtx, dispatch));

Comment: Check the line at `AsyncServlet.java:50`.

Comment: And what, may I ask, is on line 50?

Comment: Start debugging at line 50 of AsyncServlet.java.

Comment: updated with line50 content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If line 50 is this:

```
executor.execute(new AsyncRequestProcessor(asyncCtx, dispatch));
```

then the most likely immediate cause of the NPE is that `executor` is `null`.

If `asyncCtx` or `dispatch` where boxed primitive types, then you could get an NPE from unboxing `null`.  However this seems highly unlikely given the names of the variables.  They look like names of "regular" class instances to me.

Comment: you are right, I executed `System.out.println(request.getAttribute("executor"));` and got Null

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that could force a `NullPointerException` to be thrown from that line is if the `executor` object has not been intialised properly.